# how to track all function calls of some modules?

Tags: events, powershell, logging, hook

I'd like to have some usage statistics for a bunch of my modules.

It would be handy if I could run code whenever a function is called from a set of modules. Is it doable? Do powershell generate internal events we can hook on? I can not find any guidance yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me whether you're more interested in logging events or executing code (hooking).

## Logging

There are 2 places where in the event log where Powershell writes to the logs:

- `Applications and Services > Windows PowerShell`
- `Applications and Services > Microsoft > Windows > PowerShell`

On a per-module level, you can enable the `LogPipelineExecutionDetails` property. To do it on load:

```powershell
$mod = Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$mod.LogPipelineExecutionDetails = $true
```

Or for an already loaded module:

```powershell
$mod = Get-Module ActiveDirectory
$mod.LogPipelineExecutionDetails = $true
```

After that you check the first of the event log locations I listed (`Windows PowerShell`) and you'll see logs that show the calls to various cmdlets with the bound parameters.

You can also enable this via Group Policy as a Computer or User setting:

- `Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows PowerShell > Turn On Module Logging`

You can specify the module(s) you want to enable logging for.

In PowerShell v5, there will be even more detailed logging available (see the link).

#### Source

You can see more detailed information about the logging settings (current and upcoming) on [Boe Prox's blog: More New Stuff in PowerShell V5: Extra PowerShell Auditing](http://learn-powershell.net/2014/08/26/more-new-stuff-in-powershell-v5-extra-powershell-auditing/)

## Hooking

As far as I know there is no direct way to hook calls in an existing module, but I have a crappy workaround.

[You can effectively override existing cmdlets/functions by creating functions or aliases with the same name as the original](https://serverfault.com/a/642299/236470).

Using this method, you could create wrappers around the specific functions you want to track. Consider something like this:

```powershell
# Override Get-Process
function Track-GetProcess {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    # All the parameters that the original function takes
)
    # Run pre-execution hook here
    & { "before" }

    $params = @{}
    foreach($h in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.GetEnumerator()) {
        try {
            $key = $h.Key
            $val = Get-Variable -Name $key -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value -ErrorAction Stop
            if (([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($val) -and (!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($key)))) {
                throw "A blank value that wasn't supplied by the user."
            }
            Write-Verbose "$key => '$val'"
            $params[$key] = $val
        } catch {}
    }

    Get-Process @params # call original with splatting

    # run post execution hook here
    & { "after" }
}
```

The middle there [uses splatting to send the given parameters and sending them to the real cmdlet](http://www.briantist.com/how-to/splatting-psboundparameters-default-values-optional-parameters/).

The hardest is part is manually recreating the parameter block. There are ways you could likely do that programmatically if you wanted to quickly run something to hook any function, but that's a bit beyond the scope of this answer. If you wanted to go that route, have a look at some of the code in [this New-MofFile.ps1 function](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/DSC/blob/master/Tooling/DscDevelopment/New-MofFile.ps1), which parses powershell code using powershell's own parser.

Comment: There are plenty of infos thanks. I will look at the logging feature first. Make an alias for every functions (isnt it a proxy function?) doesnt make sense here are these are mine.